# Converge a.s of $\dfrac{U_k}{k}$ to $0$ where $(U_k)$ are iid, nonnegative $L^1$ random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

This problem comes up while I'm reading one of the book on Markov chains. However, to simplify things up, let $(U_k)$ be a sequence of iid random variables, $U_k \ge 0 \text{ a.s} \ \forall k$ and $\mathbb{E}(U_1) < \infty$, and we want to show that
$$
    \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{U_k}{k} = 0 \text{ a.s}
$$
Here, in the book, the author show this by using Borel-Cantelli lemma as follows, for any given $\delta > 0$
$$
    \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{U_k}{k} \ge \delta\right) \le \dfrac{1}{\delta}\mathbb{E}(U_1) < \infty \hspace{0.5cm} (1)
$$
Therefore, $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} k^{-1}U_k = 0$ a.s

That's the ***whole*** argument of the author, without any further explanation. My concern is the first inequality $(1)$, as for $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and by the Markov's inequality, we have
$$
   \sum_{k = 1}^N \mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{U_k}{k} \ge \delta\right) \le \dfrac{\mathbb{E}(U_1)}{\delta}\sum_{k = 1}^N \dfrac{1}{k}
$$
But the series $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ diverges, so how do we have that inequality ?

Of course, things are easier if we let $\mathbb{E}(U_1^2) < \infty$, then
$$
   \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{U_k}{k} \ge \delta\right) \le \dfrac{\mathbb{E}(U_1^2)}{\delta^2}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^2} < \infty
$$
So, my question is, is it possible to have $(1)$ with the only assumption that $U_k \in L^1$ or we need to have $U_k \in L^2$ ? If this possible, please show me how. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use the layer cake formula for non-negative random variables
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X] &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \ge \lambda) d\lambda
\end{align*}

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, so by your hint, then: $$ \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{U_k}{k} \ge \delta\right) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{U_k}{\delta} \ge k\right) \le \int_0^{\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{U_1}{\delta} \ge \lambda\right)d\lambda = \dfrac{1}{\delta}\mathbb{E}(U_1) $$

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn Yep, that's right!